# php pdo error handling difficulty

Tags: php

I am using firebug to see what is being returned with JSON and i get this array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 00000
)
```

With Mysql i could simple do `or die(mysql_error())`.

Here is my query, I just changed it from mysql to prepared statement and now it isn't working.

```
        $construct =  $connectdb->prepare("SELECT rate.voted as rvote, child.*, sub.actionid as usersub, child.position as cnid FROM `table1` child 
        LEFT JOIN vote rate on rate.userid=:userid AND child.id=rate.blockid
        LEFT JOIN subscribe sub on sub.actionid=child.id AND sub.userid=:userid
        WHERE child.sid=:id AND child.position=:clickedposition
        ORDER BY cnid DESC,cid DESC $finalquerylimit");         

        $construct->execute(array(':userid'=>$userid,':id'=>$id,':clickedposition'=>$clickedposition));
```

This is what i used to get the error

```
print_r($construct->errorInfo());
```

I know the query isn't wrong because it works in MySql?   any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Error code with `00000` means the statement executed successfully.

Comment: nothing is being returned with JSON, i haven't changed any code.  Any idea what the problem might be....  When i check the array in firebug it says null?

Comment: Unless it's SP from SQL Server it lies :)

Comment: when i return `$found = $construct->rowCount()`.. i get zero.  So no rows are being found.. but with Mysql rows are being found and retuned?

Comment: @user892134 `PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement `, try to use `$found = $construct->fetchAll();` to see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The execute statement returns TRUE/FALSE value upon executing the query. So, if it returned FALSE, you could show the db error to the user(or log it somewhere). Otherwise, if it is TRUE, the query was executed successfully.

For reference: [PDO Execute Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: i just checked it returns true.  Nothing is being returned though?   I haven't changed any code.. this is confusing

Comment: Did you checked the query in phpMyAdmin and does it return the correct resultset ?